# Installing solr and indexing mysql

Tags: apache, solr, lucene

Can anyone help me with Installation of solr and configuring it to mysql table.I Have tried almost all tutorials , i tried with Jetty , also tomcat.Still getting errors like Data Handler not defined or could not find solr.It's been a week , i am trying all day

Comment: For any of us to understand your problem, we would need more details. For instance, what exactly did you do to get Solr started, when you noticed "could not find solr"?

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan can you suggest me the easiest possible way or some link for indexing mysql table ?

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan and also which one to use , jetty or tomcat

Answer (score 3):

In order to get solr running, (assuming that you've downloaded solr and extract it to a location), just navigate to the `jetty` folder.

Under that there should be a `start.jar`.

Just type in `java -jar start.jar` - this should start Solr under jetty. As simple as that. For all my development purposes, I use this. I wouldn't worry about Tomcat unless the app is ready to be deployed to some server.

In order to get your SOLR instance to pull data from mysql, you need the DataImportHandler configured. [This documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) describes it well.

EDIT:

A google search for "solr mysql import" lead me [here](http://entropytc.com/importing-a-mysql-database-into-apache-solr/). It is exactly what you're after, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue and it is not easy to find simple tutorial for this. Anyway I found following tutorial and it was useful for me. 
http://lasithtechavenue.blogspot.com/2013/11/crawling-mysql-database-with-apache-solr.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hi Please take a look here.
https://github.com/vikash32/indexing-mysql-table-into-solr

i have tried to make it less messy.

Answer (score 0):

Step1:
Login to Linux and go to root folder opt ie cd /opt/

Step2:
Dowload Solr-6.6.2 from the solr link and use the below command to download solr in linux

Sudo wget http://www-us.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/6.6.2/solr-6.6.2.tgz

Step3:
Extract the service installation file

Sudo tar xzf solr-6.6.2.tgz solr-6.6.2/bin/install_solr_service.sh --strip-components=2

Step4:
Install solr as a service using the script

sudo bash ./install_solr_service.sh solr-6.6.2.tgz

Step5:To check solr server status

sudo service solr status

Step6:To Start Solr in Cloud mode in RHEL

Go to root directory ie cd /opt/
Then go to solr directory cd /solr

Opt/solr >  sudo ./bin/solr start -c -force -s server/solr -p 8983 -z zk1:2181,zk2:2181,zk3:2181

Zk1 is the hostname or ipaddress

Step7: To Create Core on solr

Go to solr directory ie cd /opt/solr

Opt/solr > sudo ./bin/sor/create -c  -p 8983,7574 -s 2 -rf 2

-s stands for no of shards
-rf stands for no of replica