# how to implement solr to index mysql database in java?

Tags: solr

i want to use solr to index MySql database and so that I can perform a faster search of data on my website.Can anyone help me with the code. I don't have any idea how to implement solr in my code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing solr and indexing mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294087/installing-solr-and-indexing-mysql)

Comment: I have done that.And the apache solr interface works fine.But now I want to use it for my website for faster search.so can you please show me an example,to implement dataImportHandler in java code?thanks in adavance

Comment: You dont need to implement DIH - it is available as a plugin. In data-config.xml, you just need to point to the database instance and pass a query. Or is your question around making requests to Solr?

Comment: yes.but i want it to be done programmatically.My apache solr interface works fine.but how to make a requests to solr from java code?can you show me an example?thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show me how to make a request to dataimporthandler  programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad. However for a head start you could have a look at [DataImport](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) in Solr.

Comment: i have configured apache solr and the interface works fine.But now i want to implement it in java code.can you help me by showing me an example.thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly do you want to implement in java? Are you looking at an embedded Solr server?

Comment: Yes I am looking for embedded dataimporthandler solr server.Can you show me an example?thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show me how to make a request to dataimporthandler programmatically?

Comment: You would use the `setRequestHandler` method for calling the `dataimporthandler. Have a look at this link http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_3_1/solr-solrj/index.html

Comment: I have check that link i can't understand anything.Can you please show me an example?thanks in adavance

Answer (score 0):

you many want to check for [Solr Data Import Handler module](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) which will help you index data from MySQL into Solr without writing any java code.

If you have downloaded Solr, You can check out the example `solr-4.3.0/example/example-DIH` (Refer to the readme.txt) which will give you an idea of how the DIH is configured and the indexing can be done.

```
CommonsHttpSolrServer commonsHttpSolrServer = new CommonsHttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr");
QueryRequest request = new QueryRequest(params);
request.setPath("/dataimport");
ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
params.set("command", "full-import");
commonsHttpSolrServer.request(request);
```

**NOTE** - The request sent is asynchronous, so you would receive an immediate response and would need to check the status to know if it was complete.

Comment: i have checked the examples.It works fine.But now i want to implement it in my website for better search and faster search.can you please show me an example,java code to index mysql database?thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show me how to make a request to dataimporthandler programmatically?

Comment: it has java code for querying solr with an http request for dataimport

Comment: I am sorry but its all jumbled up.It will be kind of you to send me an attactment.thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please send an attactment?or can you post the code on this?it will be a great help for me.And others also can benifit it.

Comment: i have tried using this......public static void main(String[] args) {
  String url ="http://localhost:80/solr/collection1";
  SolrServer server;
  SolrQuery query;
   try {
        server = new CommonsHttpSolrServer(url);
        query = new SolrQuery();
        query.setParam(CommonParams.QT,"/dataimport");
        QueryRequest request = new QueryRequest(query);
        QueryResponse response = request.process(server);
        server.commit();
        System.out.println(response.toString());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
          }
          }